# IIS Express stops after saving *.cs or *.cshtml file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-express, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

Im testing new `ASP.NET 5` web template in Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate CTP 5.
(14.0.22412.0 DP)

My problem is, that when i run application, each time i press save on any of `.cs` or `.cshtml`files, server stops. No warnings or error dialogs appear.

I can reproduce error using empty starter projects:

```
file->new project-> ASP.NET Web Application -> ("ASP.NET 5 Empty" and same with "ASP.NET 5 Starter Web")
```

After trying to locate the source of problem, i found this in output window:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Deleted -> c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\Startup.cs
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [ApplicationShutdown]: Scheduling shutdown request for debugger detach.
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\0sc2sxcq.1a1~ -> c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication4\src\WebApplication4\Startup.cs
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : [ApplicationShutdown]: Requesting shutdown.
The program '[7760] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7760] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[7348] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

So it seems that saving file deletes it, and deleting file triggers shutdown.
I don't think its intended that way.

Using View In Browser instead debugging works (but i want to use debug)

What i tried:

- Reinstalling Visual Studio
- Disabling Web Essentials/Resharper
- Running all available Target KRE versions
- Switching to Release

I would format my PC, but this seems a bit drastic.

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro

**EDIT:**

Problem persist in VS 2015 CTP **6**

("Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS" versions **1.0.0-beta2** and **1.0.0-beta3**)

Comment: Samething happening at my end as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're attempting to run and then edit your applications in debug mode (F5). Currently, when you save a file while in debug mode pre-compilation kicks in and attempts to re-compile the file you saved. This step terminates iisexpress.exe.

**To avoid this issue** I'd recommend running your applications with Ctrl+F5 (without debugger attached).

Ultimately the purpose to pre-compilation is to speed development time. While it may currently hurt the debugging experience you will notice running your application without the debugger attached results in significantly faster execution than in previous versions.

Comment: Yes, the main reason why i was thinking it is horrible, was that I couldn't edit razor files and see changes without restart. For backend  - `Edit and Continue` is not that critical... Thank you for suggestion. But still, it feels somewhat broken to terminate without any confirmation. **And it works on fresh Windows - Visual Studio Instalation** with Edit and Continue feature

Comment: I had narrowed it down to one project dependency:
` "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta1",` is working, ` "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2"` is stopping IIS

Comment: We agree! It's planned to be fixed to be more like past releases, no worries :).

Comment: I am using beta1 and its not behaving properly. I just want IIS to keep working even when i recompile the site manually. That is how I have been working since VS2005. But I suppose since its this beta stuff I hope it will properly on release. + CTRL+F5 doesnt work for me?  Another answer suggested doing righ click on project -> View -> View in Browser. This now starts IIS without any debugging and if I rebuild manually the site carries on with code changes. *phew*